# Cannot push a second URL into the queue for my Discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a proper play and stop functions. However, the problem is that I cannot add a second URL to the queue.

If I call -play URL, this command will stop the current song and skip to the new one. Also if a song finished playing, I have to disconnect the connection in order to play another song, so I am not able to implement the skip function as well.

I am using the new version Discord.js which is v.12.

```js
case "play":

function play(connection, msg) {
    var server = servers[msg.guild.id]

    server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {
        filter: "audioonly"
    }))

    server.queue.shift()

    server.dispatcher.on("end", function() {
        //dispatcher = null
        if (server.queue[0]) {
            play(connection, msg)
        } else {
            connection.disconnect()
        }
    })

}

if (!arguments[0]) {
    msg.channel.send("You need to provide a link!")
    return
}

console.log(msg.member.voice.channel)
if (!msg.member.voice.channel) {
    msg.channel.send("You must first join a voice channel!")
    return
}

if (!servers[msg.guild.id])
    servers[msg.guild.id] = {
        queue: []
    }

var server = servers[msg.guild.id]

server.queue.push(arguments[0])

if (!msg.guild.voiceConnection)
    msg.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection) {
        play(connection, msg)
    })


break

case "skip":
var server = servers[msg.guild.id]
if (server.dispatcher)
    server.dispatcher.end();

msg.channel.send("skip to the next one")
break

case "stop":
var server = servers[msg.guild.id]
if (msg.guild.voice.connection) {
    for (var i = server.queue.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        server.queue.splice(i, 1)
    }

    server.dispatcher.end();
    msg.channel.send("Stop playing")

}

if (msg.guild.voice.connection)
    msg.guild.voice.connection.disconnect()
break
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

guild.voiceConnection is undefined, replace it by guild.voice. But better solution is to shift queue in the end event before playing new song and testing if the queue is empty.